# Thread-safe DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, thread-safety

I want to make update operations to the DataTable/DataSet thread-safe. There are ~20 threads each updating ~40 rows of global DataTable using `Rows.Find(pk)` method of DataTable. Each thread will be updating distinct rows of DataTable.

I'm using the following wrapper class for DataSet. Is this approach thread-safe?

```
public sealed class MyDataSet{

    public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public static UpdateRow(key,data)
    {
        object _lock = new object();
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Find(key);
        lock(_lock){          
            dr.AcceptChanges();
            dr.BeginEdit();
            dr["col"] = data;
            dr.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called from a `for` loop.

```
for(int x=0; x<40; x++;){
    if(someCondition)
    .
    .
    .
    MyDataSet.UpdateRow(key,data);
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

Everything is done in a multithreaded environment. Is UpdateRow method thread safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not safe. You should change your code in:

```
public sealed class MyDataSet{

    public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static UpdateRow(key,data)
    {
        lock(_lock){
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Find(key);
            dr.AcceptChanges();
            dr.BeginEdit();
            dr["col"] = data;
            dr.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Your `_lock` object should be a static object in your program to make it a good lock. And your `Find` should be in the locked part.

Answer (score 1):

> Is UpdateRow method thread safe?

No it's not. You are creating a lock on a **new object** every time you enter the method. The object on which you lock has to be the same across all threads - otherwise the lock will never be considered "taken" since each thread happily creates a new lock on an object it throws away afterwards. One way to achieve this would be making the object you lock on static as well.